# what does it mean by "$\min\{X,Y\}$" where $X$ and $Y$ are random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I see this term often.

find $P(\min\{X,Y\}< z)  $      where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variable .

From the online source, I see people saying this as $P( \{X < z\} \cup \{Y< z\} )$, but I don't see why.

Can you guys please define what it means? Also for maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a statement about sets than probabilities.

$\{\omega | \min(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) < z \} = \{\omega | X(\omega) < z \text{ or } Y(\omega) < z \} = \{\omega | X(\omega) < z \} \cup \{\omega | Y(\omega) < z \}$.

You can show this in the following way if you prefer, but it is essentially the same as above: Suppose $\alpha \in \{\omega | \min(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) < z \}$, then  $\min(X(\alpha), Y(\alpha)) < z$ and so we must have either $X(\alpha) <z$ or $Y(\alpha) < z$ in which case we have $\alpha \in \{\omega | X(\omega) < z \} $ or $\alpha \in \{\omega | Y(\omega) < z \} $, or in other words $\alpha \in \{\omega | X(\omega) < z \} \cup \{\omega | Y(\omega) < z \}$.
Since $\min(X(\alpha), Y(\alpha)) \le X(\alpha)$, we see that if $\alpha \in \{\omega | X(\omega) < z \} $ then we must have $\alpha \in \{\omega | \min(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) < z \}$. The same applies to $Y$.

For $\max$, you can use $\max(a,b) = - \min (-a,-b)$, or replicate the reasoning above with $\text{or}$ replaced by $\text{and}$:

$\{\omega | \max(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) < z \} = \{\omega | X(\omega) < z \text{ and } Y(\omega) < z \} = \{\omega | X(\omega) < z \} \cap \{\omega | Y(\omega) < z \}$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(\min{X,Y}<z)$ is the probability that a realization of $X$ and $Y$ from their distributions will be such that the minimum of those two numbers is less than $z$.

For instance, for two uniformly distributed random variables from $[0,1]$, how likely is it that their minimum is less than $1/2$?  (Equivalently, how likely is it that both are $\geq 1/2$, which is $1/2 \times 1/2 = 1/4$.)

If the minimum of two numbers is less than $z$ then either $X < z$ or $Y < z$.  (If neither is less than $z$, then the minimum is not less than $z$.)  So the universes with minimum less than $z$ is the union of universes where one is less with the universes where the other is less.  (This includes universes where both are less than $z$, but their minimum is still less than $z$.  Via union, we only count such universes once, instead of twice.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the minimum of $X$ and $Y$ is less than $z$ then the union you state must be true, correct?

If the union statement is true, then the minimum of $X$ and $Y$ must be less than $z,$ right?

So if each implies the other, the two statements must be equivalent.

Comment: no, I think I have more problem with the term "minimum". what exactly do you mean minimum of X and Y

Comment: say X{x=0,1,2,3,4,5} and Y{y=2,3,4,5}, the min{X,Y}=0?

Comment: The minimum could be 0,1,2,3,4, or 5. Each has a corresponding probability. If these are discrete uniform random variables, then the probability that the minimum is 5 is ${(1/6)}{(1/4)}.$ Other cases require more work to evaluate, but are not too much more involved.